# Toggle Click or hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm working with data tables and I've loaded my table via ajax and this also populates my new row drop down.  My issue is that I can get the row to drop down but can not get it close again.  It simple just adds the same data again and again etc. until the page in manually refreshed.  Here is my click event...

```
//CLICK EVENT
$('#tblIndustry td.control').live('click', function () {
    var nTr = this.parentNode;
    var i = $.inArray(nTr, anOpen);

    if (i === -1) {
        industryDrillDown(tbls.industry, nTr);
    } //end if

    $(nTr).find('.control i').fadeOut();
}); //ends click event
```

Comment: post your related HTML codes too.. its hard to figure out what are you relly tryig to do

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.live has been depreciated as of jQuery 1.7. Instead, use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

You may also want to look into the [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that i is an integer, not a jquery object. Unless you actually have an i tag with elements inside. If this is the case then you would want the I tag to have the click so that upon clicking, it is hidden. If you are searching for the element at index try using

```
.find('.control:eq(' + i + ')');
```

or

```
$(this).fadeOut();
```

Again this is really hard to do without your html. Remember JS fiddle is you friend. :D

Comment: I havent created a js fiddle account yet

Comment: You don't need one to use it. Only if you wish to refer back to the jsfiddle at a later point and you are worried about losing the link.
You can use this one. Its just a blank save.
http://jsfiddle.net/Q5WDM/

Answer (score 0):

What is `#tblIndustry td.control`? i think it's the popup (dropdown) right?
you need to check the other click event that open your popup (dropdown) and prevent the selector from selecting the popup (dropdown) too. that way, because the event is bubbling to top, when you click you fadeout but you also open the popup (dropdown) almost instantly and also regenerating the content (adding it again).

Comment: tblIndusty is the data table td is the new table row and control is the class for that table row.  In my drop down rather than just a row with out grid lines i had it drop down a table based on the information from the ajax call

Comment: Ok, so it is a table on a dropdown. So, have you check the other click event? if your dropdown is a child of your parent input, when you assign click event in the parent input, your dropdown will also affected by it.